# Chamada ajax dentro de outra

Tags: javascript, ajax

Como esperar o retorno de um ajax para continuar a requisicao de outro?
Tenho o seguinte:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",                                
        url: 'http://uma_url_qualquer.com',
        success: function (e) {
            var item = f.items; 
           //AQUI A OUTRA CHAMADA
            $.ajax({
                 type: "GET",                               
                 url: 'http://uma_url_qualquer.com',
                 success: function (f) {
                 }
           });
          //AQUI TERMINA          
        }
    });
```

Do jeito que esta as duas executam ao mesmo tempo e da erro. Tentei usar `async`                                mas ja esta obsoleto e trava meu navegador! Como resolver?

Comment: Como tens no código é uma opção válida. O que não funciona nesse modelo?

Comment: Uso um valor pego na primeira para usar na segunda. Mas do jeito que esta a primeira executa toda e so depois a segunda executa.

Comment: É correto que uma só executa depois da outra e é possivel usar dados da primeira na segunda, mas não o contrário. Uma coisa que não percebo é porque tens `var item = f.items;` antes da segunda chamada quando `f` é um argumento da segunda e não da primeira.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode criar uma promessa, pode usar o then para executar o proxímo ajax.

**Exemplo:**

```js
function meuAjax() {
  return $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://httpbin.org/get',
    success: function(e) {
      console.log('Executou 1');
    }
  });
}

meuAjax().then(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://httpbin.org/get',
    success: function() {
      console.log('Executou 2');
    }
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Pergunta relacionada: [Ajax/JQuery - Como saber se uma requisição foi concluída?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/147453/ajax-jquery-como-saber-se-uma-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-foi-concluida/147459#147459)

Detalhe muito importante, você esta usando o retorno do segundo ajax no primeiro, e isto não é possível, sendo assim o `var item = f.items;` é acessível apenas no segundo ajax.

Comment: Promises são uma boa opção (talvez melhor que a do AP) mas não vejo que seja o problema aqui.

Answer (score 2):

Tente executar em sequencia utilizando `$.when`:

```
  $.when(
    $.ajax({ // Primeira a ser executada
    url: 'http://uma_url_qualquer.com', 
    type: 'GET',      
    success: function(data){     
            resultado1 = data;                  
    }           
  }); 

  $.ajax({ // Segunda a ser executada
    url: 'http://uma_url_qualquer.com', 
    type: 'GET',      
    success: function(data){                          
        resultado2 = data;     
    }           
  }); 

  ).then(function() {
    $('#div1').html(resultado1);
    $('#div2').html(resultado2);
  });
```